# Связи в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, связи, модель-данных

Помогите разобраться. Есть две сущности связаны третьей, то есть связь многие ко многим, один врач может работать на нескольких участках и на одном участке может работать несколько врачей. Я вынес отдельно сущность кабинет, связь получилась 1 ко многим  или кабинет тоже относится к врачам и связь многие ко многим? Если так, то получается тут две связи многие ко многим? В общем запутался, разъясните пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы определитесь что с чем связывается. На рисунке показаны связи  сущности "расписание" с другими сущностями. Вроде всё похоже на правду. Сущности не связываются между собой третьими сущностями. Для этого мугут применяться, а могут и не применяться другие классы объектов. В базе данных sql многие-ко-многим представляются таблицами связей (join table). В модели данных такие таблицы в явном виде вообще никак не представлены, они скрываются в недрах ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Если сущность Кабинет - это атрибут сущности Доктор, то неверно установлена связь. А если это атрибут сущности Расписание, то да, формально кажется, что у тебя две связи много-ко-много.

Но на самом деле их нет ни одной. Потому что Расписание - это самостоятельная сущность. В то время как связь много-ко-много предполагает непосредственную связь двух сущностей, без сущности-"посредника".

Comment: Кабинет не может быть атрибутом. У доктора есть выделенный ему кабинет, но в каждом конкретном случае может вести приём в другом. Может в его кабинете сейчас ремонт. Кроме того часто назначают не персонально к доктору, а в кабинет узкой специализации. Не важно кто там доктор, ибо он один и выбора у несчастного больного нет.

Comment: В данной схеме должны быть, вообще-то, ДВА атрибута Кабинет. Первый - это атрибут сущности Доктор (тот самый "закреплённый"). Второй - это атрибут сущности Расписание приёма. И использовать они должны одну и ту же таблицу-словарь, хранящую экземпляры сущности Кабинет, со связью один-ко-много.